# How to make sure that the Observable.map only executed on succes?

Tags: javascript, angular

I just want to make sure that code inside `map` function should be called only on success but not on failure.

```
delete(department: Department): Observable<Department[]> {
    return this.post('/delete', body).map(response => {
         let index: number = this.departments.indexOf(department);
         if (index > -1) {
             this.departments.splice(index, 1);
         }
         return this.departments;
     });
}
```

I don't know whether the code inside `map` executes only on success or not. And also, I have to return an `Observable` so , I can't apply `subscribe` function here.

Comment: AFAIK, operators such as `maps` are used to **transform** the data in the stream, not to handle the outcome of the stream. Also, what exactly do you mean by "failure"? If you still obtain a `response` after a so-called "failure", maybe you can analyze it (i.e. test `response.status`, `response.headers`...) to decide whether it's worth proceeding. If by failure you mean lower-level errors (i.e. Exception), then you could use an operator like `.catch()` to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

`Observable#map` operator will be executed on success response only (e.g. status 200). `Observable#catch` operator is intended to catch failures.

Also, `Observable#catch` operator will catch javascript errors thrown while mapping success response as well. Example:

```
fetchDashboardData(): Observable<Dashboard> {
    return this._http.get(reqUrl, reqOptions)
        .map((response: Response) => new Dashboard(response.json().items[0].dashboard))
        .catch((error: any) => {
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                // js error, e.g. response.json().items was an empty array
                console.log(error); // => “Cannot read property 'dashboard' of undefined...
                return Observable.throw('Incomplete response data!');
            } else {
                return Observable.throw('Server error!');
            }
        });
}
```

Subscribe block:

```
    this.dashboardService.fetchDashboardData().subscribe(
        (dashboard: Dashboard) => {
            this.dashboard = dashboard;
            console.log('Success fetching dashboard data!', dashboard);
        },
        (errMssg: string) => {
            console.error(errMssg); // => 'Incomplete response data!'
            // or 'Server error!'
        },
        () => {
            // finally block!
        }
    );
```

Comment: Good answer. As additional information, the second argument in the subscribe is where you can have your error function. so ..delete(department).subscribe ((success) => success, (error) => error, (complete) => complete)

Comment: so catch is must , right? so that I can redirect the error to subscribe call.

Comment: Observable#subscribe method accepts 3 callbacks: ..subscribe(onSuccess, onError, finallyFn); So, if response is successful, and mapping passed without errors, onSuccess will be called, otherwise onError will be called with the 'Javacript error occurred!' or 'Server error!' message.

Comment: What I mean by failure here is server error. You throw a custom error but I want to throw the actual error returned. `.catch((error: any) => {return Observable.throw(error)} `

Comment: @Avinash Raj If you want to handle errors, then yeah, it's must.

Comment: @Avinash Raj You can return the actual error, however you will need to handle it in the component then (when subscribing to the Observable).

Comment: .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error)); // return error without handling it..

Comment: @seidme what if you failed to specify the catch part?

Comment: @Avinash Raj Unhandled server error will be passed to onError callback provided as second argument of .subscribe method.

Comment: What's the point of catching the error to re-throw it immediately?